# No logro subir mi repositorio Nextjs a Vercel

Tags: nextjs

Hola cuando subo mi repositorio a Vercel obtengo:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
> at exports.useContext >(/vercel/path0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
> at p (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/642.js:1:19159)
> at h (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_error.js:1:2477)
> at Wc (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
> at Zc (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
> at Z (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
> at Zc (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
> at Z (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
> at Zc (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
> at Z (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
> Error occurred prerendering page "/blog". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Lo mismo me dice para /404 y /500 pero yo no codifique esas paginas.

Por otro lado este es mi codigo:

```
    import Layout from "../components/Layout";

const blog = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h1>BLOGhello world</h1>
        </Layout>);
};

export default blog;
```

Comment: Estás usando useContext en tu código? Lo estás importando correctamente en el archivo que lo usa?

Comment: No..no uso useContext en ningun lado por eso es raro.

Comment: Que versión de nextjs, node y bundle (npm, yarn, pnpm...) estás usando?,